# Insert multiple rows with associative entity

Tags: mysql, join, database-design, sql-insert, associative-table

I'm facing a problem for a project I'm working on.

I have a MySQL database that I use with a Node.js script (thanks to the *mysql* npm package).

I have two entities, **A** and **B**, with a many-to-many relationship. Between them, there's a associative entity table, named **Map_A_B**. Foreign-keys are defined between both **A** and **Map_A_B**, and **B** and **Map_A_B**.

Here is how it looks like:

[image]

The problem I'm facing is when I'm trying to insert data (multiple rows). Because I'm doing an INSERT of many rows, then I don't have the id for each table and can't fill the mapping table (let's say that each **A** contains 100 **B**'s).

Before, instead of having an associative entity table, I just had a foreign-key inside of **B** that helps me to store the **Aid**, and this was pretty easy to do. But now, I can't do this anymore.

I've done some research before, using JOIN I can SELECT / DELETE without any problem, I'm just a bit lost about this multiple row INSERT...

Do you have an idea about how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After inserting a row, ask for its id via `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.